# How to simulate a click tag in a flash banner

Tags: javascript, flash, click, openx

Our sales people accepted flash banners without a click tag and then scream in anger when our ads server (openx) didn't count correctly the clicks.

So, I'm looking if exists some way of "simulate" a click tag, I don't know exactly how, maybe with some JavaScript.

Comment: as far as I've seen, they gotta have the clickTag/clickTAG in the compiled swf source. There shouldn't be a way to inject it since that's a security problem with Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a blank `<span>` or `<div>` element in front of the embedded flash, and then use a JavaScript event listener to open the desired URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the link as a variable to your Flash movie in the embed code.